# How to sync several parallel processes and run them in a loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

Currently I have this situation:

```
import concurrent.futures

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

# get data1
data1_future = executor.submit(get_data1)
# get data2
data2_future = executor.submit(get_data2)

data1_df = data1_future.result()
data2_df = data2_future.result()

# compare data
compared_data_future = executor.submit(compare_data, data1_df, data2_data)

compared_data_df = compared_data_future.result()

# store output data to disk
executor.submit(store_data, compared_data_df, output_dir)
```

This is working fine for a single run, but I would like to have everything running in a loop so that:

- data1 is being sampled every n minutes
- data2 is being sampled as soon as previous data1 sampling is done
- compare_data is being run after each data2 sampling
- store_data is being run after each compare_data is being run.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you may want to use the `schedule` library (https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/): create a function running these four steps one by one and run this function with schedule

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That will probably solve the problem of running the get_data1 every n minutes. I'm further wondering how to sync individual processes so that get_data_2 triggers compare_data and new run of get_data_2 at the same time so those two processes are running in parallel.

Comment: you have to use [callbacks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback) to attach a function to run once your future finishes

Comment: "and are always called in a thread belonging to the process that added them". I would like for get_data_2 to trigger compare_data and new run of get_data_2 in two separate threads for them to run in parallel. Is that a possibility?